# How to add css after div gets loaded using script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In application we have refiner sharepoint webpart. It is being binded after page load.

I want to add css `display: none` to one div inside that webpart using jquery/ javascript.

I have tried delegates and live function of jquery, but these doen't have load/ ready triggers.

Is this possible to do with `setInterval` function?

Comment: Share code of that webpart...

Comment: Share the code of that webpart....

Comment: People here will have to understand how the content you want to modify is being loaded in order to help.  Is it part of the original page?  Is it being loaded dynamically?  If so, please show the code that loads it.  Also, if the target div can be reached with a CSS selector, then you can just create a CSS rule that targets it without worrying about the load timing.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with a `display: none` property then use that class on your generated div.

Answer (score 0):

As u mentioned you can wait via window.setInterval(function), or instead bind "DOMNodeInserted" on any parent where the child will be inserted later.

example:

```
$('#element').bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(oEvent)
{
    // do something
});"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Callback function.

Chech this example:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_callback.asp